# For loop for Index and Match/min function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I have a code that works in stand alone excel and the same code that does not work in VBA.

```
  =INDEX(I8:Q8,MATCH(MIN(IF(I9:Q9="height",I10:Q10)),I10:Q10,0))

   Cells(PoleRow, 3).Formula = "=INDEX(AK12:CH12,MATCH(MIN(IF(AK13:CH13=""height"",AK14:CH14)),AK14:CH14,0))"
```

Really Really struggling with this. The first code is from sample data from hard coding excel. This code works and does what I what. The second code is a conversion of the sample data into VBA form that I wish to work. I think I need a FOR loop for each record.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: #Value!# @ScottCraner

Comment: Change `.Formula` to `.FormulaArray`